# Stop ItemsControl Cache

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, itemscontrol

So I have an `ObservableCollection<User> User` in my ViewModel. `User` has a property called `Username` and the two users are equal if their `Username`s are equal (Using `IEquality<T>`).

So somewhere in my code, I am doing this: `this.Configuration.Users[0] = user` where `user` is another user which I get after editing.

What happens now is that if both of the Users are `equal` (As in their usernames are equal), the UI is not updated, which is not what I expect. Any changes to the new User is not reflected in the UI.

I suppose the UI is only updated if a there is a change which is detected by the Default Equality comparer. I don't want this. Anytime a user is changed by whatever means, I want the UI to be updated.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: As of now, I have this workaround :

```
this.Configuration.Users.RemoveAt(index);
this.Configuration.Users.Insert(index, user);
```

Comment: does a `User` class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: What event are you watching? I couldn't replicate the behavior with adding an int, and replacing it with the same int (it fired the `CollectionChanged` event)

Comment: Yes it does. `Username` does not fire Propertychanged event. But another property such as `State` which is an Enum does have property change implemented. Any change to that enum is not reflected in the UI after using the indexer of ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Rob I think it's because of IEquality<T> and that they are both "equal", so maybe the UI does not notice it. If I change the Username, the UI is updated accordingly.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements. When two User instances are considered equal, you can't expect the ObservableCollection to raise a CollectionChanged event when the one is replaced by the other. Either you change the equality condition, or you update all changed properties on the existing object. Or perhaps you write your own special ObservableCollection that uses `object.ReferenceEquals` to determine object equality.